# Does Azure auto scaling replicate new files?

Tags: azure, scaling

Does anyone know if Azure autoscaled instances replicate the files from the original web app? Lets say if the web app has been autoscaled to 20 instances, we now need to deploy some changes(dlls etc). How does this work? Will the change we deployed to the original web app get replicated to the existing auto scaled instances? Or does Azure kills all the scaled instances and then start scaling again? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Azure Web App; the web site folder on the D: drive is actually a shared network drive, just mounted to look like it's local. So, all twenty instances use the same folder, meaning there is no need to replicate anything.

(For avoidance of doubt, Cloud Services are completely different)